Select entity and ids of its surrounding entities
This is my query
It is meant to return the selectedResponse and its next and previous ids. As you can see, the Where clause currently constrains the results. I tried a nested select and CTE, both resulted in errors. In my previous implementation, I used nested selects with limit one, that resulted in n+1. I can't use joins, due to the issues with the parent ids (it was getting ids from another requests).
@Query("""
      SELECT
      new code.modules.conversation.data.jpa.projection.ResponseWindow(
        res,
        LAG(res.id) OVER (PARTITION BY res.request ORDER BY res.created),
        LEAD(res.id) OVER (PARTITION BY res.request ORDER BY res.created)
      )
      FROM ResponseEntity res
      WHERE res = :selectedResponse
    """)
    ```


IIRC JPQL does not support windowing functions. So you will need to convert this to a native query and map out the result.

This question is similar to: Does Hibernate (HQL) Support Common Table Expression. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
